# JPA/Hibernate dynamically injecting entity manager

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA/hibernate setup with multiple entity managers.  What I am trying to do is dynamically injecting the entity manager in an abstract class used by multiple schemas with the same entity definition -- the tables are exactly the same across different databases in a single MySQL server.  I am trying not to write unnecessary duplicate code, but I can't seem to find a way to inject the persistence context dynamically without duplicating a lot of code.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an abstract DAO with all the basic list, update, delete methods and extending by another abstract DAO in which I set the entity manager for that particular set.  Any DAOs that extend the last one will have the correct annotated entity manager associated with them.  From that point on I am able to reuse my models, and all I have to do is extend the right DAO on my service layer.

The magic happens by calling setEntityManager(EntityManager em) using the @PerisstenceContext with the persistence unitName.  **I am not entirely sure why this works, but seems to do the trick.**

Here's what I did:
AbstractJpaDao:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractJpaDao <T>{
    private Class<T> clazz;
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public final void setClazz(final Class<T> clazzToSet) {
        this.clazz = clazzToSet;
    }

    @Transactional
    public T getById(final long id) {
        return entityManager.find(clazz, id);
    }
    //... all the others ...
}
```

InheritedDao1:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class InheritedDao <T> extends AbstractJpaDao <T>{
    //This is what allows me to inject the entityManager by its annotation
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}
```

InheritedDao2:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class OtherInheritedDao <T> extends AbstractJpaDao <T>{
    //This is what allows me to inject the entityManager by its annotation
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "otherPU")
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}
```

Service1:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class MyService extends InheritedDao<MyModel> {
    public MyService() {
        setClazz(MyModel.class);
    }
}
```

Service2:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class OtherService extends OtherInheritedDao<MyModel> {
    public OtherService() {
        //same model as used in MyService
        setClazz(MyModel.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, do you need to *change* the EntityManager that exists in a DAO instance? If yes, I'd say just switch your connection pool instead.

If instead you want to select to which instance to connect, set up the necessary keys in one or more profiles, then use that to get the necessary connection properties for your connection pool.

If you want to have multiple instance of the same DAO, use qualified beans and constructor injection to get the proper entity managers to them (abstract away everything else like factory / pool creation into methods).